# Fixed pipeline to glsl gl_Normal / vnormal / v_normal

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

The more I read the more confused I become. I am trying to learn getting from old `opengl1` fixed pipeline to modern gl. I learned a lot already but for one thing I am still unsure about. In old tutorials its just used as `gl_Normal`, in newer its often referred to `vnormal` or `v_normal`.

In older versions I didn't have to take care about that, also in fixed pipeline it seems to be provided automatically. So where to get this or rather, how to calculate it? Must it be done in c++ or can it be done in vertex or fragment shader as well from vert position (in old tutorials referred as `gl_Vertex`)?

A sample or pseudo code would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal never came automatically. Even with fixed pipeline, you had to provide normals yourself.

`gl_Normal` was pre-defined vertex shader attribute that came from `glNormalPointer`. In latest GLs (not sure about actual version, probably 4.*) these functions was deprecated so *all* attributes have to come from `glVertexAttribPointer` - no predefined attributes, programmer have to bind every array to attribute location himself.

So `normal`, or whatever it is called - is just named attribute. You have to get its location (with `glGetAttribLocation`) and assign array containing vertex normals (normals to sufrace at the point of specified vertex) to that location.

As for calculating normals - it is trivial for flat surfaces (just a cross-product of two triangle edges), but for smooth shading - normals have to be interpolated between nearest polygons. It is usually done in 3D mesh editors and just exported to file.

Comment: "As for calculating normals - it is trivial for flat surfaces (just a cross-product of two triangle edges), but for smooth shading - normals have to be interpolated between nearest polygons. It is usually done in 3D mesh editors and just exported to file." - thanks, that finally fills my gap! Wondering why I never read it that way in any tutorials, in these the values seemed to be taken always "out of nowhere" for me